# Does character length of domain affect seo rankings?

Tags: seo, domains

My domain : CreditCardPaymentGateways dot in  even after 6 months is not ranking well.
Could it be due to length of it?

Also I've blocked backlinks to some directories( without nofollow) using robots.txt.

I suspect either is playing spoilsport in good rankings of my site, which I've optimized well and has least competition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard of the domain name length affecting SEO.

Google doesn't appear to show any inbound links to your site (via Google Search) - that probably won't be helping matters.

Comment: it's not .com but .in website. I selected this meaningful phrase website because it contains relevant search terms

Answer (score 1):

Domain length should not impact your chances of ranking well. However taking a look at:

Your site it would appear to be a holding page with low value content this probably means you don't get much traffic. Plus your domain name is made up of a number of keyword phrases so I assume you were wanting to rank for exact match searches.

I would look to improve content and do some link building.

Answer (score 1):

**About your specific website**
Assuming you are talking about the ".com" website: I am sorry to say, but about everything is wrong with your website when considering the "rules" you have to follow to gain proper SERP results. A good starting point would be to start reading the webmaster guidelines from Google: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769

**About the question you posted**
The search engines would are not necessarily "punishing" websites that have "long" domain names. However, from a users perspective you would want to read a domain name that is easy to read and one that reflects the contents of the website it represents. This DOES NOT mean summing up a string of keywords and place ".com" at the end of it. It has no added value and might even be seen as a "spammy" activity.

Comment: I think his site is www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in

Comment: That site is a train wreck, too.

Comment: I'd be happy if you elaborated on "train wreck".