# which domain is better for SEO purpose?

Tags: seo, domains, keywords

i'm building a website to convert PSD files to PNG and i have two options to choose a domain:

1. convert-psdtopng.com
2. convertpsdpng.com

I need the word convert to be there too.

Which one do you think is better to rank on "convert psd to png" keyword?

Thanks!

Comment: There are dozens of questions already on Webmaster regarding domain names. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10027/does-character-length-of-domain-affect-seo-rankings is a good one in regards of character length, and for using the word `to` in the domain see > http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34132/does-having-a-google-stop-word-in-a-domain-name-have-less-seo-benefit-than-not and another consideration you should look at is your domain being too EMD http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/36211/best-strategy-for-exact-match-domain-emd-along-side-branded-domain

Comment: @bybe Thanks for the links but my question is more specific and the information in those links doesn't provide a clear answer...

Comment: Your question involves comparing a domain with hyphens and stop words to a domain without which both questions have already been asked on Webmasters already. Regardless if these questions have correct, clear or wrong information they remain a duplicate. If a question has no answers, poor answers or incorrect answers it’s just because no one has left a great one! And again this wouldn’t merit another being made to get a prompt answer. We have many ways of bumping old questions to attract better answers. To bump old posts edits, up votes and bounties can attract better answers.

Comment: My recommendation would be to use our chat channel and ask your question there. Myself and many others of the great members we have on the site will give you their opinions on what they believe is best.

Comment: Great, I'll take a look in a few moments. Thanks for the understanding.

Comment: chat not working for me... nevermind

Comment: I've left an answer on the chat system for you > http://chat.stackexchange.com/ click webmasters. Thanks.